# How do I make one custom state dependent on another?

Tags: salt-stack

How do I make one custom state dependent on another with a requisite in an sls file?

**Example:**  Two [custom states](http://docs.saltstack.com/ref/states/writing.html) in a `_states/seuss.py` module:

```
# seuss.py
def green_eggs():
    return {'name': 'green_eggs', 'result': True, 'comment': '', 'changes': {}}

def ham():
    return {'name': 'ham', 'result': True, 'comment': '', 'changes': {}}
```

I want `ham` to be dependent on `green_eggs`:

```
# init.sls

have_green_eggs:
  seuss.green_eggs:
  - require:
    - user: seuss

have_ham:
  seuss.ham:
  - require:
    - ???
```

How do I make `???` a dependency on the successful completion of `green_eggs`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would want:

```
have_ham:
  seuss.ham:
    - require:
      - seuss: have_green_eggs
```

However, you are currently defining two states of a `seuss` resource, which means that either a `seuss.ham` or a `seuss.green_eggs` called `have_green_eggs` could fulfil that requirement.

If you don't want that, then you will have to define the states in separate files (e.g. `seuss_ham.exists` and `seuss_green_eggs.exists`).

Comment: Continuing what Daniel said, the different states in in your custom state module should be mutually exclusive. For example, for the service 'nginx' you wouldn't set up one state which was `nginx: - service.running` and one which was `nginx: - service.dead`. So too your custom state module should only contain states which would not be used simultaneously.